# How to login arcgis secure service in Flex using 2.5 version?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api, flex, flex-2.5

I know, that I can use [IdentityManager](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/apiref/com/esri/ags/components/IdentityManager.html) class to show login+password form for secured services. But it's available in version 3.0, and I'm using 2.5. How can I provide access for secured service in my case? I also know, that I can use token generation, but token is bound to unique IP address and I need to use the application on many machines.

Thanks

Comment: Why not upgrade to Version 3.0?

Comment: @MLowry it's not compatible with our flex sdk

Comment: I don't follow. Why are you stuck on an old SDK?

Comment: @MLowry that's a requirement, I'm not responsible for it

Comment: Are your services secured on the map server end? Do you want users to have to log in (or do you want the application to hide the log in)?

Comment: @Bjorn Svensson, I've already implemented quiet login with token generation, thanks